# How to get the initial URL in Scrapy

Tags: scrapy

I need to get the first URL which Scrapy spider currently processes to map result to it. More spicifically. If an URL for scraping is `abc.de` and it's redirected to `https://www.abc.de/en`, I want to get `https://www.abc.de/en` as `url` and `abc.de` as `initial_url`. My code is:

```
class SpiderTst(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'spider_tst'
    start_urls = ['vrgroup.fi']

    def parse(self, response):
        tst_item = TstItem()
        tst_item['url'] = response.url
        ...
        tst_item['initial_url'] = response.request.url
        yield tst_item
```

But the 'url' and 'initial_url' values are equal.

Comment: The initial URL is the element in `start_urls`, just use `start_requests` and pass the URL with `cb_kwargs` or something.

Comment: if the url was redirected, than `response.url` and `response.request.url` should not be the same.  create a [mre].

Comment: vrgroup.fi redirects to https://www.vrgroup.fi/en/, but initial and final urls sre the same and equals to https://www.vrgroup.fi/en/ I also updated the code to the minimal reproduceble example

Answer (score 1):

If your initial start URL is not a Full URI with an appropriate scheme, then there really is no way to get it through request and response objects and your best bet would be SuperUsers suggestion in the comments.

However, if your initial URL does have a scheme then the redirect chain is available in the response meta dictionary.

To demonstrate using `scrapy shell`:

```
>>> fetch('http://vrgroup.fi')
2023-06-01 13:07:26 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://www.vrgroup.fi/> from <GET http://vrgroup.fi>
2023-06-01 13:07:26 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://www.vrgroup.fi/fi/> from <GET https://www.vrgroup.fi/>
2023-06-01 13:07:27 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.vrgroup.fi/fi/> (referer: None)
>>> response.url
'https://www.vrgroup.fi/fi/'
>>> response.request.url
'https://www.vrgroup.fi/fi/'
>>> response.meta['redirect_urls']
['http://vrgroup.fi', 'https://www.vrgroup.fi/']
```

Answer (score 0):

I did as @SuperUser adviced because of the problem @Alexander mentioned - the URL is not always "full" in my case. So I pass the URL as a call argument:

```
    def parse(self, response):
        for ...:
            # here initial_url is passed
            yield response.follow(url, functools.partial(self.parse_sublink, initial_url=url))

    def parse_sublink(self, response, initial_url):
        # here initial_url is used
```

Primary parse function can be called the same way with passing the initial URL as an additional argument. To pass a paramether to a callback you need to use `functools.partial`, otherwise the same URL will be passed at each iteration.